# Jframe disappears in @Test JUnit

Tags: java, swing, junit

I am doing some automation using JUnit 4 with Java and now I want to add some graphic mode using Jframe, I have this code in @Test (gui is the JFrame object):

```
 @Test
 public void initData() {
   try{
     setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     gui.setTitle("Linkedin Candidates Search Tool");
     gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     gui.setSize(400, 200);

     gui.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

     gui.add(ScreenTools.createLabel("Enter password: ", 5, 80, 110, 15));
     textopassword = ScreenTools.createTextField(120, 80, 150, 20,"");
     gui.add(textopassword);

     boton = ScreenTools.createButton("Generate",5,120,60,15);
     gui.add(boton);

     gui.setVisible(true);

     accion e = new accion();
     boton.addActionListener(e);

  }catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error M001. " + e);
   }
```

and then in the listener of "boton" (it is a button) I have some actions for automation:

```
public class accion implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    try{
        openingTabs();
    }catch (Exception f ){
        System.out.println("Error M001. " + f);

    }
  }
 }
```

My problem is that Jframe window is being closed and doesn't let me to perform the action with the button, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, JUnit ends after last line `boton.addActionListener(e);` *immediately*. This is normal. A typical swing application starts a dedicated thread for the UI:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
```

BTW, one of the traits of good tests is being automated. Just saying.